# No handlers could be found for logger requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool

Tags: python, django, logging

In my django application i use library `requests`. In the header file, where i use requests:

```
try:
    # for Python 3
    from http.client import HTTPConnection
except ImportError:
    from httplib import HTTPConnection
if settings.DEBUG:
    HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1
logging.getLogger("requests.packages.urllib3")
logging.getLogger("requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool")
```

In django settings:

```
LOGGING = {
    handlers: {
        'requests.packages.urllib3': {
            'handler': ['console'],
            'propagate': False,
            'level': LOGLEVEL,
        },
        'requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool': {
            'handler': ['console'],
            'propagate': False,
            'level': LOGLEVEL,
        }
    }
}
```

In console i get message:
`No handlers could be found for logger "requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the handlers wrongly in the `settings.py` file.
You should specify the `package` that you want log in the `loggers` child of the `LOGGING` dictionary.

Try something like this:

```python
LOGGING = {
    "formatters": {
        "verbose": {
            "format": "%(asctime)s %(levelname)s:%(name)s:L%(lineno)s: %(message)s"
        }
    },
    "handlers": {
        "console": {
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "formatter": "verbose",
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
        },
    },
    "loggers": {
        "requests": {
            "handlers": ["console"],
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "propagate": True,
        },
        "requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool": {
            "handlers": ["console"],
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "propagate": True,
        },
    }
```